# Sorting dates with time

Tags: java, sorting, datetime

I am trying to sort dates with the times inside of my array strings. The dates sort just fine but I need to sort the times with the respective date. SORT TIMES NOT DATES. My column class is set up date. My date123 array prints out:

Here is the problem:

```
        Variables:
         Date[] date123 = new Date[8];
         String rowdata[] = new String[8];


        String array1[] = { dateString1(current time), "10:18:17 PM"};
        String array2[] = {"1999/01/19 08:09:10 AM", "10:00:33 AM"};
        String array3[] = {"1989/12/05 09:00:56 PM", "07:12:19 AM"};
        String array4[] = { dateString1, "10:18:17 PM"};
        String array5[] = {"2001/06/10 08:09:10 AM", "10:40:53 AM"};
        String array6[] = {"2000/01/12 05:00:56 PM", "07:12:19 AM"};
        String array7[] = { dateString1, "10:18:17 PM"};
        String array8[] = {"2010/01/09 10:09:10 AM", "3:00:33 PM"};


        rowdata[0] = array1[0];
        rowdata[1] = array2[0];
        rowdata[2] = array3[0];
        rowdata[3] = array4[0];
        rowdata[4] = array5[0];
        rowdata[5] = array6[0];
        rowdata[6] = array7[0];
        rowdata[7] = array8[0];

        for(int t = 0; t<rowdata.length; t++)
        {
            DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a");

            try {
                date123[t] = sdf.parse(rowdata[t]);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

     @Override
     public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return Boolean.class;
                case 1:
                    return String.class;
                case 2:
                    return String.class;
                case 3:
                    return Date.class;
                default:
                    return Date.class;
                }
            }

            data11.add(date123[t]);
```

---

Output:

> Aug 21,2014
>
> Jan 19, 1999
>
> Dec 05, 1989
>
> Aug 21, 2014
>
> Jun 10,2001
>
> Jan 12,2000
>
> Aug 21,014
>
> Jan 09,2010

But this is what is being put in table: just the date and not times. The dates are sorted, but I need the times to be printed with the dates, but I want the times to be sorted not DATES... Please help .

Comment: What time zone are you interested in? (Imagine two values which are 9pm and 11pm in your time zone, but 11pm and 1am in mine...)

Comment: It doesnt really matter. I just the times sorted. And I feel like I am close but I cant figure it out

Comment: I don't see how you can say it doesn't matter - if we use my time zone, we get an order of B, A, but if we use your time zone, we get an order of A, B. I'm finding it pretty hard to understand what you're asking, to be honest. It might be simpler if you formatted your post more readably...

Comment: @JonSkeet: the OP probably only has to worry about a single TZ. Seems like a homework assignment to me...

Comment: Every item in the array has a date and time. I want the times sorted in the table and MDT is the time zone

Comment: and its not a homework assignment by the way. @thkala

Comment: @sayit: I can't understand what the exact problem is. Is it that the times are not printed? That they are not sorted? Both? Please show us a *complete* program that we can test and paste the *actual* output of that program. Then tell us what you want the correct output to be like. As it is, this question is unanswerable...

Comment: The times are not being printed and they are not being sorted because they arent being printed. The posted code is all I have out of the generics of setting up the jtable. All i need is the times being printed and sorted

Comment: @sayit: could you at least add the declarations of the variables, so that we don't have to guess?

Comment: @thkala Variables: Date[] date123 = new Date[8]; String rowdata[] = new String[8];

Comment: not true @SeanVanGorder the date123 array at index one contains: "Thu Aug 21 10:56:19 MDT 2014"... As you can see in the output, only the DATE is being printed and not the time... I need the time to be printed with the date

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). We can help if you create a minimal example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You say you want the values sorted, yet your random code extract above does not include a sort call (that I can see).  Obviously, if you want the values sorted, you need to invoke a sort method.  And, given that you want a non-standard sort, you probably need to define your own compare routine for the sort.  Please refer to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T[],%20int,%20int,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Comment: I am using a table sorter @HotLicks

Comment: Well then use your sorter to sort the data the way you want.  Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JTable to display your records and TableRowSorter to sort your rows, here you go.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sort Records based on Time");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Object rows[][] = { { "1999/01/19 08:09:10 AM", "10:00:33 AM" },
    { "2000/01/12 05:00:56 PM", "07:12:19 AM" },
    { "2010/01/09 10:09:10 AM", "3:00:33 PM" } };

String columns[] = { "Date", "Time" };

TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Class<? extends Object> getColumnClass(int column) {
    return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    }
};

JTable table = new JTable(model);

TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
sorter.setComparator(0, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String record1, String record2) {
    if (record1 != null && record2 != null) {
        final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        try {
        Calendar time1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar time2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        time1.setTime(sdf.parse(record1.substring(record1.indexOf(" "))));
        time1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MDT"));
        time2.setTime(sdf.parse(record2.substring(record2.indexOf(" "))));
        time2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MDT"));

        if (time1.before(time2)) {
            return -1;
        } else if (time1.after(time2)) {
            return 1;
        }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        // Do Nothing
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }
});

table.setRowSorter(sorter);

JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);

frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.setSize(300, 150);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to sort a record based on the time field. Each record will have the date and time but you wanted to do sorting based on the time. If so, the below piece of code would help. If not let me know your requirements clearly.

```
final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");

String[][] records = new String[][] {
    { "1999/01/19 08:09:10 AM", "10:00:33 AM" },
    { "2000/01/12 05:00:56 PM", "07:12:19 AM" },
    { "2010/01/09 10:09:10 AM", "3:00:33 PM" } };

List<String[]> sortedList = new LinkedList<String[]>(Arrays.asList(records));
Collections.sort(sortedList, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    public int compare(String[] record1, String[] record2) {
    if (record1 != null && record2 != null
        && !(record1.length < 2 || record2.length < 2)) {
        try {
        Calendar time1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar time2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        time1.setTime(sdf.parse(record1[1]));
        time1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MDT"));
        time2.setTime(sdf.parse(record2[1]));
        time2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MDT"));

        if (time1.before(time2)) {
            return -1;
        } else if (time1.after(time2)) {
            return 1;
        }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        // Do Nothing
        }
    }
    return 0;
    };
});

for (String[] record : sortedList) {
    System.out.println(record[0] + ", " + record[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Every date has a time associated with it. I want to sort the times by clicking on the column header in my table. Currently, I am using RowSorter. table.setSorter(sorter). For my getColumnClass. How could I use your method of sorting by clicking on the column header

Comment: @sayit - Please actually look at the documentation for whatever kit you're using to display the data.  It's all in the documentation.  (And we can't look at the documentation for you because you haven't given us even a tiny clue as to what you're using to display the data.)

Comment: @sayit - I have added another answer to use comparator in TableRowSorter. I hope this would help you for sure.